# Postgres service failing on Win10, manual startup works

Tags: postgresql, service, windows-10

As of today, suddenly, my `Postgres 9.6` `Windows 10` service fails to start up the server. Here is what I used to register the service:

```
pg_ctl register -N PostgreSQL-9.6.10 --pgdata=%DATA_HOME%\Postgres ^
    --log=%DATA_HOME%\Postgres\server.log
```

When I go to my Windows service control panel, when I hit start for this new service, which is registered okay, it reports that the service is started for a brief moment and then it switches the status to stopped. I am unable to find any logging of the service itself, to get a trace of why this might be happening.

The service does start fine when I do it manually:

```
pg_ctl -D %DATA_HOME%\Postgres -l %DATA_HOME%\Postgres\postgres.log start
```

Any idea what the problem might be and how to recover my service?

Comment: Did you look in Windows logs (eventvwr)? What's the user starting de service? Perhaps user Service Account doesn't have permissions in data directory...

Comment: I did but I was confused in which folder within the event viewer to look. There was nothing under System